# Mistake in proof of polynomials being continuous?

Tags: analysis, functions, polynomials

I can't seem to get my head around the underlined in the proof attached being correct. Plug x as 3, y as 4 and n as 2 and you end up with -7=-14 for example.

[image: Proof]

What is going on?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Where do you get the $14$ from? $(3-4)(3^1\cdot 4^0 + 3^0\cdot 4^1) = (-1)\cdot 7 = -7$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: "In view of the above theorem"... what is this theorem?

Comment: $$3^2-4^2=(3-4)(3+4)\iff-16=-1\cdot7\iff-7=-7$$

Comment: @sranthrop continuity of addition, no doubt

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I think so too, but sometimes they prove that multiplication is also continuous and then the polynomial-example follows exactly like here, even if it is then not necessary. That's what I wanted to point out just as a little remark.

Comment: @sranthrop Just that you can add, multiply and divide continous functions to get another continuous function.

Comment: Ok, so then this proof is - as I suspected - not necessary, since $x^n=x\cdot\ldots\cdot x$ is the product of the continuous function $x\mapsto x$ with itself, $n$-times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting $x=3$, $y=4$ and $n=2$ gives the same answer:
$$3^2-4^2=-7$$
$$(3-2)(3+4)=-7$$

Comment: Well this is embarassing. Ha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As your left hand side is correct.

Right hand side -

$(3 - 4)(3^1 + 3^0 \cdot 4^1)$

= $(-1)(3 + 1 \cdot 4)$

= (-1)(3 + 4)

= -7

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{gathered}
  x^{\,n}  - y^{\,n} \quad \left| \begin{gathered}
  \;y \ne x \hfill \\
  \;x \ne 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  = x^{\,n} \left( {1 - \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)^{\,n} } \right) = x^{\,n} \left( {1 - \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)} \right)\left( {\frac{{1 - \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)^{\,n} }}
{{1 - \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)}}} \right) \hfill \\
   = x^{\,n} \left( {1 - \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)} \right)\left( {1 + \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right) + \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)^2  +  \cdots  + \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)^{n - 1} } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = x\left( {1 - \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)} \right)x^{\,n - 1} \left( {1 + \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right) + \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)^2  +  \cdots  + \left( {\frac{y}
{x}} \right)^{n - 1} } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {x - y} \right)\left( {x^{\,n - 1} y^{\,0}  + x^{\,n - 2} y^{\,1}  +  \cdots  + x^{\,0} y^{\,n - 1} } \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$